# How to control Gandalf "flying bricks"?

Tags: pc, lego-lord-of-the-rings

I'm having a heck of a time trying to stack the bricks together using Gandalf's brick levitation ability.

It seems nearly impossible to move them a single stud left/right/back/forward.

I'm running on Windows 7, with keyboard controls.
Is there a way to do this well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same issue when playing on the PS3 version, so there's no fix to be had by using a pc controller instead.

Give up on trying to construct pretty, even staircases; just cobble together whatever looks solid enough to stand on.  You don't need to assemble them correctly, you just need to assemble them good enough to use.

On be bright side, there's only a few of them in the entire game, probably because the developers realized mid-development that their system was flawed to the Undying Lands.

Comment: Same experience here. There is very few that need to be perfect (I can only think of one infact, to do with the coloured blocks) and the rest are just so you can climb on them. As long as you've built something that you can climb on, use it.